# How to display elapsed time in seconds in CSV data - Jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I am new to Jmeter and working on JDBC. I am interested to know:

1. How to change field/header names while exporting data to csv file.
2. How to display elapsed time in seconds instead of milliseconds.

I would really appreciate, if you please define each step. Being a newbie, it would be easier for me to follow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. The field names are defined in the [CSVSaveService.java](https://github.com/apache/jmeter/blob/v3_3/src/core/org/apache/jmeter/save/CSVSaveService.java) file, you will need to get [JMeter sources](http://jmeter.apache.org/svnindex.html), amend field names as required and rebuild JMeter. See [How to write a plugin for JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_tutorial.html) article for more information
2. There you can change it in the same file like:

   ```
   elapsed = Long.parseLong(text) / 1000 // convert ms to seconds
   ```

   However I wouldn't recommend going for these approaches as there could be side effects in reporting systems.

Instead of patching JMeter you can add a [JSR223 Listener](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Listener) and write your own CSV file using [Groovy code](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)

For example this is how you can write elapsed time in seconds into a new file called `results.csv`

```
def myFile = new File('results.csv')
myFile.append(sampleResult.getTime() / 1000)
myFile.append(System.getProperty('line.separator'))
```